# How do I get Absolute Root Links in ASP.NET MVC 2.0 beta Areas?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, beta, areas

The link for logging in looks like this:

```
<%= Html.ActionLink("Log On", "LogOn", "Account") %>
```

which yields the following link in the browser:

```
http://localhost:2300/Account/LogOn
```

However, if I switch to an `Area`, such as `Content`, the Login link now looks like this:

```
http://localhost:2300/Content/Account/LogOn
```

...which fails of course, because there is no `AccountController` in the `Content` Area.

How do I change my call to ActionLink so that it yields `http://localhost:2300/Account/LogOn`
?

Comment: Have you tried RouteLink instead?

Comment: That's a good idea.  Let me check it out.

Comment: When you say "switch to an Area", do you mean you navigate to an area and thus ActionLink creates a link assuming its for Area "Content"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [RouteLink](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.html.linkextensions.routelink.aspx) instead.